# Drools rules export/import when upgrading

Tags: import, export, upgrade, drools

I am working with an old version of Drools (5.2). I can export all of the rules in an XML format that has more than 6 million lines in it. I can not find any way to import that file into the most recent version of drools. Is this a legitimate way to do the upgrade? Is there a better way? I need to to a mass migration due to the sheer number of rules I'm dealing with (more than 17,000). I have been struggling for a long time reading documentation trying to figure this dilemma out.

Comment: What kind of version are you trying to update to? 5.2 is ancient and the syntax has changed quite a lot. How many rules do you have? I don't think there's an automatic way to import them in 7

Comment: I'm upgrading to 7.27

Comment: Oh, and we have more than 5000 rules.

Answer (score 0):

In the 5.2 version, there is a way to create and deploy a snapshot. On the same screen, there is a button to "View Package Source". With as many rules as we have, it took some time and even failed a few times, but eventually, I was able to view that source. I copied the text and pasted it into a text editor and saved it as a .drl file. Copying that way included the line numbers and a '|' character. There are probably other ways to do it such as importing into excel, but I wrote a little java program that stripped out that unwanted data. I could then import that file directly into my new version of the workbench using the "Import Asset" functionality once I had created a project. I have done some tweaking since then, but that is the gist of what I needed. The file validates but I have not tested yet to see if the rules work properly.